# setTimeout with arguments

Tags: javascript

having a bit of a headache on trying to work this out. What I want to do is have a custom setTimeout with arguments **with out** having to create a function to pass it. Let me explain by code:

**Want to avoid:**

```
function makeTimeout(serial){
  serial.close();
}

setTimeout(makeTimeout(sp.name), 250);
```

what I want to do is somehow just call a 1 liner by like:

```
setTimeout(function(arg1){ .... }(argument_value), 250);
```

Can this be done or can you only pass in a no argument function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can pass it an anonymous function that invokes `makeTimeout` with the given arguments:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  makeTimeout(sp.name);
}, 250);
```

There's also an alternative, using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
setTimeout(makeTimeout.bind(this, sp.name), 250);
```

This function, however, is an ECMAScript 5th Edition feature, not yet supported in all major browsers. For compatibility, you can include `bind`'s [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility), which is available at MDN, allowing you to use it in browsers that don't support it natively.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BqckR/)**.

Comment: It should be noted that the value passed to `makeTimeout` will be the value of `sp.name` when the function is called, which might be different to the value it had when `setTImeout` was called.

Comment: According to http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind, bind is now supported by the major browsers.

Comment: As RobG said, to make this thing work 100% you need to use a closure
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures
By the time the timeout expires, the value `sp.name` may have changed.

Comment: I'm not really sure why that bind was the only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to declare a separate function, you can use an immediately invoked function expression and closure, e.g.

```
// Parameter to use
var bar = 'bar';

// Function to call
function foo(arg) {
  alert(arg);
}

// Go…
setTimeout(
  (function(arg1){
    return function(){
      foo(arg1);
    };
  }(bar)), 2000);
```

Alternatively, you can use the function constructor:

```
setTimeout( Function('foo(bar)'), 2000);
```

Or you can use a string:

```
setTimeout('foo(bar)', 1000);
```

which is essentially the same thing. Now wait for howls of "*but that's like using eval, and everyone knows eval is evil and a massive security breach — all your firstborn are doomed!*"

But seriously, `eval` (and the Function constructor) are inefficient and can lead to lazy programming, so use another option, such as the first above.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the ability has been added to some browsers pass parameters to setTimeout:

**syntax:** `setTimeout (function (p1,p2) {},1000,p1,p2);` **(add as many params as you want)**

If you want to ensure it works everywhere, you can use the attached code.

**Note:** If you want to set a timeout immediately after installing it, it's best to use the callback parameter and do it in there

**for example**

```
installSwizzledTimeout(function(param1,param2){
    setTimeout(myFunc,200,param1,param2);},param1,param2);
}
```

This is because it uses a trick to detect if it is needed, by setting a very short timeout and counting the parameters.

```
window.swizzledSetTimeout = function (fn, ms) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        //console.log("Bypassing swizzledSetTimeout");
        return window.originalSetTimeout(fn, ms);
    } else {
        var args = [];
        for (i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args.push(arguments[i])
        };
        //console.log("Setting swizzledSetTimeout for function (",args,") {...} in ",ms," msec");
        var retval = window.originalSetTimeout(function () {
            //console.log("Invoking swizzledSetTimeout for function (",args,") {...}");
            fn.apply(null, args);
        }, ms);
        return retval;
    }
}

function installSwizzledTimeout(cb) {
    var args = [];
    for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i])
    };
    setTimeout(function (arg) {
        //console.log("arguments.length:",arguments.length,window.setTimeout.toString());
        if (arguments.length == 0) {

            function doInstall() {
                //console.log("Installing new setTimeout");
                window.originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
                window.setTimeout = function setTimeout() {
                    return window.swizzledSetTimeout.apply(null, arguments);
                };
                if (cb) {
                    cb.apply(null, args);
                };
            }

            if (window.setTimeout.toString().indexOf("swizzledSetTimeout") < 0) {
                doInstall();
            }
        } else {
            //console.log("existing set time supports arguments ");
            if (cb) {
                cb.apply(null, args);
            };
        }
    }, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a method that needed a constant timeout setting also having parameters to the final executed function, so I did as follow using anonymous functions:

```
function checkPageLoaded(checker, callback, nextCallTime) {
    return () => {
        let checkoutLoader = document.querySelector(checker);
        if(checkoutLoader === null)
            callback();
        else
            setTimeout(checkPageLoaded(checker, callback, nextCallTime), nextCallTime);
    }
}
```

and then just call it as follows:

```
setTimeout(checkPageLoaded('.loader', reloadPagination, 500), 500);
```

This way the desired function to be executing with the arguments will be the one defined as an anonymous one.