# Please explain the differences between this "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" and "Self Invoked Anonymous Function"

Tags: javascript

Inspired from this Stackoverflow question, the answer by João Silva: [setTimeout with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451844/settimeout-with-arguments)

I was wondering if someone could explain to me exactly how this code snippet differs from the latter:

```
// Parameter to use
var bar = 'bar';

// Go
setTimeout(
  (function(arg1){
    return function () {
        console.log(arg1); //ya arg1 has the value: 'bar'!
    }
  }(bar)), 2000);
```

I was expecting the parentheses to be slightly different and I understand that this is a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (coined by Ben Alman I believe) combined with a closure but I don't exactly understand how this code executes.

I was picturing a self invoked anonymous function invoked by a closure, which I understand how it works, at least mildly.

```
 // Parameter to use
    var bar = 'bar';

// Go
setTimeout(
  (function(arg1){
    return function () {
        console.log(arg1); //ya arg1 has the value: 'bar'!
    }
  })(bar), 2000);
```

So both work, and it is only one parentheses difference between the two code snippets, and again I am not a javascript expert but I intuitively feel both of these javascript snippets are extremely cross browser compatible. But what really is the different between the two?

Comment: Your examples doesn't make much sense, Your IIFE are supposed to return a func reference to be set as callback for setTimeout? What you have will just get invoked immediately.

Comment: But neither snippet gets evoked immediately, both are invoked after the allotted 2 secs for the timeout...

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are right, I updated my answer, now both js snippets get called after the allotted 2 sec time out

Comment: FYI, "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" and "Self Invoked Anonymous Function" are synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference at all between two variants of code.

Moreover, actually parenthesis are redundant there. It'd work even if you write this piece of code the following way:

```
// Go
setTimeout(
  function(arg1){ // let's get rid of braces
    return function () {
        console.log(arg1); //ya arg1 has the value: 'bar'!
    }
  }(bar), 2000);
```

It works because of `FunctionExpression` concept. Parenthesis are only needed to differentiate `FunctionExpression`s from `FunctionDeclaration`. In fact, parenthesis could be replaced with any operator, like `~`, for example.

**Note**: even thought this code could be written without parenthesis, I strongly object doing it, because of parenthesis now are something like a pattern or a keyword saying "Look! I'm useless bracket, probably placed here for reason like immediately invokation of this function". So code becomes a bit more clear this way.

There are plenty discussions on `FunctionExpression` vs `FunctionDeclaration` on the web, so I won't repeat once again. Take a look at past SO question: [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/1190430)